# react router 4 "Not Found" page with nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Let's say I have these routes:

```
   <Switch>
    <Route path="/my-profile" component={MyProfile} />
    <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
   </Switch>
```

Handling 404 page works okay if I type anything other than `my-profile` or logout in the address bar. However, if I will type `.../my-profile/paththatdoesntexist`, I will still see the profile page. How to handle such cases? to show not found page regardless of how much nested the path is.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar my question is about nested rotues

Comment: still same concept.

Comment: could you please explain more? I have the `Switch` component in place, but it doesn't solve the issue with nested routes..

Comment: use exact path.

Comment: lol man, I was thinking that we don't need the exact prop with Switch component.. Seems like it works as expected now, can you please add your answer here so I can mark it as correct? I believe it will be helpful for other client-side routing beginners like me.

Comment: @mcmxc, wrote an answer that scales well with nested routes on the Duplicate question. Please do have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `exact` prop in `react-router-4` as follows in your routes.

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/my-profile" component={MyProfile} />
  <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
 </Switch>
```

For more reference you could read here [exact: bool](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool)